# Example for Time Series with Drift and one with Trend

Tags: time-series, trend, intercept

after going through a few posts here on CrossValidated, StackOverflow and Google, I am still puzzled how I can detect whether a time series has a "drift" and how it differs from trend. Here are four questions that directly relate to each other. I want to avoid creating 4 posts for each of these.

1. Does "drift" just mean a linear upwards trend? If so, then is "trend"
   always exponential?
2. What's the difference between "drift" and "intercept"?
3. Deseasonalizing and detrending might be part of the pre-whitening
   process of a time series. I wonder what to do with drift?
4. When applying an Augmented Dickey Fuller Test after deseasonalizing
   and detrending, should I then consider "const" or "none"?

Comment: 1. A linear trend in a differenced series becomes quadratic (rather than exponential) in the series in levels.